# `sql/cyanaudit--1.0.0.sql', needed by `installdata'

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, audit-trail, audit-logging

i am trying to install Cyan Audit for my postgres db. 
according to doc, i have download it but when i run `make install` it says,

```
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-9.3/extension'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 cyanaudit.control '/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/'
make: *** No rule to make target `sql/cyanaudit--1.0.0.sql', needed by `installdata'.  Stop
```

i have google it, and try all solutions but nothing work for me.
.

Answer (score 0):

This has been corrected in cyanaudit-1.0.1. Please download the latest and let me know how it goes! Thanks.